# How to find lines between two timestamp in unix file

Tags: awk, sed, grep, unix-timestamp

I have a below log file and need to find the lines between two random time stamp b/w "2018-04-12 14:50" to "2018-04-14 14:20"

Input :

```
2018-04-12 14:43 Error Hello      
2018-04-13 11:33 Error Hello1    
2018-04-14 15:43 Error Hello2  
2018-04-14 12:22 Error Hello3  
2018-04-15 19:44 Error Hello4  
2018-04-16 16:43 Error Hello5
```

Output :

```
2018-04-13 11:33 Error Hello1  
2018-04-14 15:43 Error Hello2  
2018-04-14 12:22 Error Hello3
```

Note : I have tried with below sed command but it showing blank output because the mention time is not there in file.

```
sed -n '/2018-04-12 14:50/,/2018-04-14 14:20/p' log_file
```

Comment: Why would `2018-04-14 15:43` be included? That doesn't appear to be within the range in your `sed` example.

Answer (score 2):

`awk` provides string comparison with the `>` and `<` operator and string concatenation by simply joining adjacent strings. A simple version to collect entries between `"2018-04-12 14:50"` and `"2018-04-14 14:20"` could be:

```
$ awk '$1" "$2 > "2018-04-12 14:50" && $1" "$2 < "2018-04-14 14:20"' log
2018-04-13 11:33 Error Hello1
2018-04-14 12:22 Error Hello3
```

(**note:** `"2018-04-14 15:43 Error Hello2"` does not fall within the requested range)

Answer (score 1):

The line with `2018-04-14 15:43` from your sample does not fall within the range you specified in your `sed` command.

Anyway. here's what I've got:

```
awk -v a="2018-04-12 14:50" -v b="2018-04-14 14:20" \
  '$1 " " $2>=a{n=1} $1 " " $2>b{n=0} n' log_file
```

Or, broken out for easier reading (and commenting):

```
awk -v a="2018-04-12 14:50" -v b="2018-04-14 14:20" '
  $1 " " $2 >= a { n=1 }  # If the current line is greater than our start, set mark
  $1 " " $2 >  b { n=0 }  # If the current line is greater than our end, unset mark
  n                      # If our mark is set, print the line
' log_file
```

This solution evaluates the first to "words" on each line against the input variables you set with awk's `-v` option.

This works because awk's `>` operator evaluates sorting order when used with strings, and your dates are thankfully ISO 8601, so sorting works.

Comment: Just a thought... you could possibly do something such as `a='2018-04-12 14:.[0-9]' -v b='2018-04-14 14:.[0-9]'`

Comment: @l'L'l .. Sure, but if you made the variables regular expressions, they couldn't be used for sort comparisons. That would be a different answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the datetime fields are sequential in nature (your third line is out of order so I'm assuming here it should have the date `2018-04-13`, which I've modified it to), you can do this with a simple `awk` command as per the following transcripts (ignore the `pax>` bit, that's my prompt):

```
pax> awk '$1"_"$2>"2018-04-14_14:20"{exit} $1"_"$2>="2018-04-12_14:50"{print}' infile
2018-04-13 11:33 Error Hello1
2018-04-13 15:43 Error Hello2
2018-04-14 12:22 Error Hello3
```

The first clause simply exits when you find a date beyond the desired end. The second clause will (if the first clause hasn't yet caused an exit) print out each line where the date and time is at or beyond the start.

---

If those lines really *are* allowed to be out of order and you want lines within the date range wherever they may be in the file, you just have to process the entire file printing out those that match:

```
pax> awk '$1"_"$2>="2018-04-12_14:50"&&$1"_"$2<="2018-04-14_14:20"{print}' infile
2018-04-13 11:33 Error Hello1
2018-04-13 15:43 Error Hello2
2018-04-14 12:22 Error Hello3
```

Changing back to your original file, with the date of the third line being out of order, gives you the correct output in that case as well:

```
2018-04-13 11:33 Error Hello1
2018-04-14 12:22 Error Hello3
```

Comment: @oguzismail: That's his prompt, ignore it.

Comment: @I'L'I Oh, I don't understand why would anyone change it to anything other than $

Comment: @oguzismail, I have it set based on which user I'm logged in as. I reserver `$` for root user only, anything else uses the user name.

Comment: @abhishekchechani, glad to hear it was helpful - just keep in mind the general guideline on SO is that you should upvote any answers that you find useful, and accept the one that best answers your question (whichever that may be).

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -v beg='2018-04-12 14:50' -v end='2018-04-14 14:20' '{cur=$1" "$2} beg<=cur && cur<=end' file
2018-04-13 11:33 Error Hello1
2018-04-14 12:22 Error Hello3
```